# Customer Reviews is not showing up on Product Detail page in magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2.4

[image]

The following container is empty
The reviews are approved in the backend and showing up there as usual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add the below block in your layout I have added in  catalog_product_view.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="product/view/list.phtml" before="product.review.form" />
                 </block>
```

It was Working Fine